# How do I hang a kino flo from the ceiling?

Tags: lighting, grip

I have a [four-foot single bank kino fixture](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1061358-REG/kino_flo_sys_4801_120u_4_single_bank_select_ve_system_120u.html) that I need to mount on the ceiling of our media lab.  It needs to be angled precisely because it's for lighting a green screen (currently, it's mounted on a low stand on the floor, but I'm trying to get it out of the way).

The ceiling is drop tile, hanging 20" from the subfloor above.  Ideally, I'd like to fasten the light very securely to the subfloor via some type of hanger.  Telescoping hangers sound like a good way to get through the drop ceiling, but [all the ones I've found](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=telescoping%20hanger&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top%20Nav-Search=) are designed to clamp to a lighting truss, which we don't have.  I've seen [drop ceiling scissor clips,](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=scissor%20clips&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top%20Nav-Search=) but they don't look sturdy enough for a light of this size.  So far, the best thing I can come up with is an [18" wall stud](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/264556-REG/Mole_Richardson_500764_Wall_Plate_with_Baby.html) to [the lolipops we already use,](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/258327-REG/Kino_Flo_MTP_BL41_Twist_On_Mounting_Plate_w_Baby.html/prm/alsVwDtl) but I don't know if it's safe or wise to use either of these upside-down.

I would appreciate any insight from more experienced grips, links to more information, or ideas about better forums to ask.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably try the lollipop, just be sure to wire it to safeties (safety cables) anchored directly to the subfloor as well.  This will prevent it from falling in the event the lollipop fails.

I'd probably do some weight tests of the mount before putting it up as well to make sure it is strong enough to hold it in position well.  There is certainly no reason such a mount couldn't be strong enough, I just am not familiar with that particular one.